# InnoSetup error "could not call proc" with call to external dll

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Our InnoSetup uses an external dll to grab and check an xml file for the paths to data files.
This works fine in most cases, Windows XP, 7, 10 (32/64bit). But for some few users this fails and for me it fails in Crossover 19 for macOS 10.15.
So first I added a delayload to the inno script to get past the "cannot import dll" runtime error.

But then I get "could not call proc" runtime error.
The InnoSetup debugger pointed me at `procedure GetExultGamePaths` of our script.

Code in our dll:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall GetExultGamePaths(char *ExultDir, char *BGPath, char *SIPath, int MaxPath) {
    MessageBoxDebug(nullptr, ExultDir, "ExultDir", MB_OK);
    MessageBoxDebug(nullptr, BGPath, "BGPath", MB_OK);
    MessageBoxDebug(nullptr, SIPath, "SIPath", MB_OK);

    int p_size = strlen(ExultDir) + strlen("/exult.cfg") + MAX_STRLEN;
    char *p = new char[p_size];

    // Get the complete path for the config file
    Path config_path(ExultDir);
    config_path.AddString("exult.cfg");
    config_path.GetString(p, p_size);
    setup_program_paths();

    const static char *si_pathdef = CFG_SI_NAME;
    const static char *bg_pathdef = CFG_BG_NAME;

    MessageBoxDebug(nullptr, ExultDir, p, MB_OK);

    try {
        // Open config file
        Configuration config;
        if (get_system_path("<CONFIG>") == ".")
            config.read_config_file(p);
        else
            config.read_config_file("exult.cfg");

        std::string dir;

        // SI Path
        config.value("config/disk/game/serpentisle/path", dir, si_pathdef);
        if (dir != si_pathdef) {
            Path si(ExultDir);
            si.AddString(dir.c_str());
            si.GetString(SIPath, MaxPath);
        } else {
            std::strncpy(SIPath, si_pathdef, MaxPath);
        }

        // BG Path
        config.value("config/disk/game/blackgate/path", dir, bg_pathdef);
        if (dir != bg_pathdef) {
            Path bg(ExultDir);
            bg.AddString(dir.c_str());
            bg.GetString(BGPath, MaxPath);
        } else {
            std::strncpy(BGPath, bg_pathdef, MaxPath);
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::strncpy(BGPath, bg_pathdef, MaxPath);
        std::strncpy(SIPath, si_pathdef, MaxPath);
    }

    delete [] p;
}
```

The part of the InnoSetup Script

```
procedure GetExultGamePaths(sExultDir, sBGPath, sSIPath: String; iMaxPath: Integer);
external 'GetExultGamePaths@files:exconfig.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  sBGPath: String;
  sSIPath: String;
begin
  if CurPageID = DataDirPage.ID then begin
    if bSetPaths = False then begin
      setlength(sBGPath, 1024);
      setlength(sSIPath, 1024);
      GetExultGamePaths(ExpandConstant('{app}'), sBGPath, sSIPath, 1023 );

      BGEdit.Text := sBGPath;
      SIEdit.Text := sSIPath;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

The `GetExultGamePaths(ExpandConstant('{app}'), sBGPath, sSIPath, 1023 );` is what is producing the "could not call proc" runtime error.

I have no idea why that fails on only a few systems.
The full code for our dll and the script is at https://github.com/exult/exult/blob/master/win32/
The dll's code is in exconfig.* and the InnoSetup script is in exult_installer.iss

Comment: Is any of those "few users" using a real Windows system?

Comment: Yes, one is using Windows 10 Pro without any Anti-Virus except Windows Defender. This is the latest one who has a problem, there have been other people with real Windows versions.
But it seems as if something odd is happening for some people.

Comment: What version of Inno Setup are you using? Is it the Ansi version?

Comment: Our initial installer was done with the old 5.0.x Inno Setup (because some things need to be adapted to newer versions) but even the very latest 6.x is not working as I described.
So yes, it's not yet Unicoded but why would that work generally and fail for some Windows versions?
(our official installer can be found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/exult/files/exult-all-versions/1.6/exult-1.6.0-win32.exe/download)

Comment: Doesn't your DLL have some common but not-guaranteed dependency? Like Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable?

Comment: It only depends on msvcrt.dll and that is provided by Windows 10 and emulated by Crossover

Comment: On the affected machines, can you load the DLL to any other application?

Comment: I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Write a simple (console) application that does [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw).

Comment: I have no idea how to write such an application...
I investigated further. We only rely on msvcrt.dll and at least for Wine/crossover it seems to be an old regression that I need to get behind via regression tests...

Comment: Just start new project in Visual Studio from "Console App" template and make it call `LoadLibrary` with some error reporting. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Through the help of Piotr in our Wine bug report https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49033 it was discovered that using the mingw tool "dllwrap" is broken and added invalid relocation data.

NOT using dllwrap was the solution and fixed it for my Wine/Crossover install. Still waiting for the last user to report back who had this problem on a real Windows 10 installation.

Thanks for your help